# Browsing and playing videos in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

To watch videos in an HTML5 web player requires us to add the source of the video in the HTML code like this:

```
 <video id="example" class="video" controls preload="none" width="500" height="300"
  poster="abc.jpg" data-setup="{}">
        <source src="../87D645D1d01.ogv" type='video/ogg' /> 
 </video>
```

So is there any way with which we can browse a media file in our local file system irrespective of the OS and then add the pah to the SRC: part of video element like we do it in any desktop based video players and then play it?

Regards.
Anuj.

Comment: I think you want to add file from other computer and play that file if this task you want then have some play with javascript or jquery to add input from that input file and add then in source.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava : I don't want to add a file from some other computer, but from my own "local" Computer. And I have gone thru some websites but none helped, that's why I posted this question here.

Comment: Then add <input type="file" name="datafile"> and run that file by taking that link I think jquery or javascript will not work use some scripting language for that but it's better you should download on your website and then play for better security.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. Your video must be online somewhere. If you have no other options just put in on your Dropbox and link it from there.

Comment: @JanPetzold: Even if I put a file in my Dropbox, how can I select that file dynamically and then put it in the src for playing?

Comment: @AnujKaithwas give its full path dynamically there are many method to give dynamic value so try it and have some play around code then only you will get some experience out of it.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava: I know, it is illegal for the browser to upload anything in its content locally as it is a security issue, however, base64 is used to evade this problem. Know of it?